# Refactoring To Remove Static Methods Code Smell

Tags: php, zend-framework, refactoring, static-methods

I have the current basic structure for each domain object that I need to create:

```
class Model_Company extends LP_Model
{   
    protected static $_gatewayName = 'Model_Table_Company';
    protected static $_gateway;
    protected static $_class;

    public static function init()
    {
        if(self::$_gateway == null)
        {
            self::$_gateway = new self::$_gatewayName();
            self::$_class = get_class();
        }
    }

    public static function get() 
    {
        self::init();

        $param = func_get_arg(0);

        if($param instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract)
        {
            $row = $param;
        }
        elseif(is_numeric($param))
        {
            $row = self::$_gateway->find($param)->current();
        }

        return new self::$_class($row);
    }

    public static function getCollection()
    {
        self::init();

        $param = func_get_arg(0);

        if($param instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract)
        {
            $rowset = $param;
        }
        elseif(!$param)
        {
            $rowset = self::$_gateway->fetchAll();
        }

        $array = array ();      

        foreach ($rowset as $row)
        {
            $array[] = new self::$_class($row);
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

I initially tried to refactor the static methods into the parent LP_Model class only to learn finally what "late static binding" means in the php world.

I'm just wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to refactor this code so that I don't have to redeclare the same three functions in every domain object that I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php

abstract class Model_Abstract
{
    protected $_gatewayName = null;
    protected $_gateway = null;

    protected function _init()
    {
        $this->_gateway = new $this->_gatewayName();
    }

    protected function __construct($row = null)
    {
        $this->_init();
        if ($row) {
            $this->_data = $row;
        }
    }

    public static function getAbstract($class, $param)
    {
        $model = new $class();
        if($param instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract)
        {
                $row = $param;
        }
        elseif(is_numeric($param))
        {
                $row = $model->_gateway->find($param)->current();
        }

        return new $class($row);
    }

    public static function getAbstractCollection($class, $param = null)
    {
        $model = new $class();
        if($param instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract)
        {
                $rowset = $param;
        }
        elseif($param === null)
        {
                $rowset = $model->_gateway->fetchAll();
        }

        $array = array ();

        foreach ($rowset as $row)
        {
                $array[] = new $class($row);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    abstract public static function get($param);
    abstract public static function getCollection($param = null);
}

class Model_Company extends Model_Abstract
{
    protected $_gatewayName = 'Model_Table_Company';

    public static function get($param) {
        return self::getAbstract(__CLASS__, $param);
    }

    public static function getCollection($param = null) {
        return self::getAbstractCollection(__CLASS__, $param);
    }
}

class Model_Table_Company extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'company';
}

$model = Model_Company::get(1);
print "Got an object of type ".get_class($model)."\n";

$models = Model_Company::getCollection();
print "Got ".count($models)." objects of type ".get_class($models[0])."\n";

?>
```

Unfortunately, to make the functions easy to call, you have to duplicate `get()` and `getCollection()` in each subclass.  The other option is to call the function in the parent class:

```
$model = Model_Abstract::getAbstract('Model_Company', 1);
print "Got an object of type ".get_class($model)."\n";

$models = Model_Abstract::getAbstractCollection('Model_Company');
print "Got ".count($models)." objects of type ".get_class($models[0])."\n";
```

You can rename the base class and its function names if you want to go that route.  But the point is that **you must name the child class in one place or the other**:  either make a boilerplate function in the child class as in my first example, or else name the class in a string as in my second example.

Comment: Thanks once again Bill. I know that you mentioned late static binding in a previous answer, but it wasn't until I started refactoring the code that I realized what the implications were of that limitation. Looking at your first solution, it seems pretty intuitive though.

Comment: And while inheritance among the static properties and methods would be the most elegant solution, at least now the get and getCollection methods in each class are limited to a single line of code as opposed to a lot of duplicated code.